# Entity Framework - Generated Relationship is Wrong

Tags: entity-framework

Just starting to use EF and have fallen at the first hurdle so to speak.

I've got two classes:

```
public class Hero
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}

public class League
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Hero> Team { get; set; }
}
```

Now there is nothing in my code to stop me having a hero which is a member of two leagues:

```
        League A = new League() { Name = "A Team" };
        League B = new League() { Name = "B Team" };
        Hero me = new Hero() { Name = "Richard" };

        A.Team = new List<Hero>();
        A.Team.Add(me);

        B.Team = new List<Hero>();
        B.Team.Add(me);
```

However when I run "Update-Database" from package manager it generates my DB with the foreign key on the hero -effectively meaning my hero can only be a member of 1 league:

```
 PSEUDO:
 TABLE HERO == ID,NAME,LEAGUE_ID
 TABLE LEAGUE = NAME,ID
```

This is effectively stopping my classes from working correctly as a hero can now only be a member of 1 league... How can I get EF to pick this up?  I guess what it needs is a many to many relationship but it isnt building one..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want a League to have many Heroes, but a Hero to be in many Leagues. As such, this is a many-to-many relationship, requiring that you have a link table object between them, and restructure it as follows (shown here using Code-First with Data Annotations):

```
public class Hero
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HeroLeagueLink> Leagues { get; set; }
}

public class League
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<HeroLeagueLink> Team { get; set; }
}

public class HeroLeagueLink
{
   [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Hero")]
   public virtual int HeroID { get; set; }
   [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("League")]
   public virtual int LeagueID { get; set; }

   public virtual Hero Hero { get; set; }
   public virtual League League { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do a many to many relationship you need to have a league collection on the hero entity to.

```
public class Hero
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<League> Leagues { get; set; }
}

public class League
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Hero> Team { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This fixed the model correctly.  Thanks - surprised that I had to do it, but when I give it a bit more thought I suppose it makes sense as otherwise all relationships would have to be many to many by default :S

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through configuration as well in case you did not want to have a collection defined on your hero class.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<League>().HasMany(x => x.Team).WithMany();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```